# Deriving $p = mv$ from translational symmetry (momentum conservation law)?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

> "In classical mechanics, momentum is defined as the quantity which is
>   conserved under global spatial translations or, alternatively, as the
>   generator of spatial translations."
>   (G.Parisi, Quantum mechanics)

From this definition (the generator of spatial translation), how can I obtain the analytical expression of the momentum (i.d. $p=mv$)?

Answer (score 5):

If we have some coordinates $q_i$ and some momenta $p_i$, then a generator of a transformation is defined as a function $g(q_i, p_i)$. By definition, this generates the transformation

$$q_i \to q_i + \epsilon \frac{\partial g}{\partial p_i}$$

$$p_i \to p_i + \epsilon \frac{\partial g}{\partial q_i}$$

So if we want the generator of translations, we want

$$q_i \to q_i + \epsilon$$

where $q_i = x$, some particular rectangular coordinate, and also

$$p_x \to p_x$$

(since we want to generate only translation without changing momenta). These imply $g = p_x + c$. Setting $c=0$, we see that x-momentum is the generator of translations in the x-direction.

You can't really show $p_x = m\dot{x}$ unless you make some assumptions about the Hamiltonian. If we assume $H(x,p_x) = \frac{1}{2m}p_x^2 + V(x)$, then Hamilton's equations give

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_x} = \dot{x} = \frac{p}{m}$$

as you requested.

All the above will only make sense if you've studied analytical mechanics from a source that happened to leave out generators. If not, you'll probably want to review the Hamiltonian formulation of mechanics. Chapter 2 of Shankar's *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* is an overview of analytical mechanics specifically aimed at getting you ready for quantum mechanics and includes a discussion of generators.