# What is the reason behind the equation $p = mv$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Now this is a very basic question, might look stupid too, but I am not able to understand it. I tried to imagine what momentum really is, and it is the impact of an object. I understood how [momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) works, but cannot understand its mathematical formulation. We all know that $p = mv$, but how does this equation work? I mean just by multiplying mass and velocity, how are we able to get this impact? Is there any derivation to this equation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deriving $p = mv$ from translational symmetry (momentum conservation law)?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87774/)

Comment: It just is: it's an observed (and tested) law.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no derivation for it. This is a definition. And the reason we make such a definition is the fact that the sum of momenta in an isolated system is conserved, so it's a very useful quantity to have around. Note that in special relativity if we defined momentum as $p=mv$, then momentum conservation does not hold anymore. So momentum is redefined as $$p=\dfrac{mv}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$  so that the law of conservation of momentum hold again. It's all a matter of definition. Now why it's conserved is another story and it can be proved using [Noether's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) theorem.